# Recursively counting unique objects inside nested vectors

Tags: java, recursion, vector, tree

I would like to count the number of unique objects which are inside a particular Vector. For example, I have a class `Person` which has `Vector<Person> family`. I 'm trying to find a way to count the length of the extended family. There could be relations between people such as:-

```
Mike is related to Pete;
Mike is related to John;
John is related to Amy;
```

Mike would have an extended family of 4 (which includes himself).

I figured the only way to do this is with recursion and I have something like this so far.

```
   public int getExtendedFamily(Person person) {

            // Add the current person if he/she does not exist
            if (!(lineage.contains(person))) {
                lineage.add(person);

                // If the person has no direct family
                if (person.getFamily().size() == 0)
                    return lineage.size();
                else {
                    // Otherwise iterate through the family members
                    for (Person familyMember : person.getFamily()) {
                        return lineage.size() + getExtendedFamily(familyMember);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Person already exists...
                return lineage.size();
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

I've created a new vector `lineage` to keep track of the unique people I come across.

Obviously I know I'm some way off with this code as my `lineage.size()` isn't right. I just can't get my head around how to structure the recursion, Any guide would be appreciated. Even if it's just pseudocode!

Kind Regards,
Ben

**updated code, appears to work**

```
public int getExtendedFamily(Person person) {

    // If the person exists just return counter, 
    //and go back up the call stack;
    if ((lineage.contains(person))) {
        return counter;
    } else {

        // Otherwise add the person to the lineage data structure
        // and continue
        lineage.add(person);

        // Loop through current persons family
        for (Person family_member_ : person.getFamily()) {

            // If the current family member index is not in the lineage
            // then increase the counter and recursively call getExtendedFamily,
            // to count that persons unique family members.

            if (!lineage.contains(family_member_)) {
                counter++;
                getExtendedFamily(family_member_);
            };
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Don't return inside the for loop: increment a counter in the loop, return after.

Comment: "I've created a new vector lineage to keep track of the unique people I come across." Don't use a vector, use a Set.

Comment: Search for "union-find".

Comment: Thankyou, so far i think i've nailed it. Updated question to show.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably just be the vector's size plus one, assuming the relationships are all saved.

If you are getting into generations, where the descendants are not reported in the grandparent, the recursive way to do it would be to return the size of the vector and return if there are no children.

If there is no requirements that the relationships are fully saved, pass a set to the recursive function and save to the set.  Return when the vector is 0.